# need to show List of items between , top and bottom bar,

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout in which two bars , one at top , another at bottom will be there, and one listview between these two bars, But question here is , between the top and bottom bar, i need to show list of items, where both top and bottom bar will be there in their place, only listview will be scrollable.

below is my xml layout , sorry for the lengthy question, Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBADDNEW"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ad_user_l" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETSEARCHTEXT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBSEARCH"
          android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search_64" />

</LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"

>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/LLforList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity ="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/IVimageIcon"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_farmer" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/TVFLNAME"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:text="Some Name"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blankbarbottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/FLlayoutLIst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnMainMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mainmenu_on" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_off" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/exit_off" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ListView for your List. It's scrollable so you don't need a ScrollView. Refer to http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html on how to use a simple ListView with an Adapter.

And you should also use a TabHost for your Tabs. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: I did. You should think about my answer for a minute ... and you should learn to use the right UI elements.

Comment: so how do i set a fixed bar, with simple listview, and i need to show different image with different row .. how am i gonna achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Layout that you want to add as the `Header` and `Footer` of the ListView and then you can add them to the ListView,

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Comment: its seems helpful, can i make a listActivity, and the adapter by extending BaseAdapter,  in this same activity can i do the following you mentioned.

Comment: You can make a sub class that extends BaseAdapter in the same class that extends ListActivity.

Comment: Thanks Lalit, let me try it, will get back to you asap.

Comment: ya sure you can get back to me I am in [Casual Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)

Comment: i tried that, but the thing is that , the header and footer are not fixed, i want to add fix bars, at both places, top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

ithink you can use listView.addheadview  and listView.addrootview
edit:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_height="36dip" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/cloth_xixian_bg"
android:id="@+id/headclothesroom">
<Button   android:id="@+id/redianroom"
    android:layout_width="100dip" 
    android:layout_height="36dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textSize="18sp"
     android:textColor="@drawable/color_wenzi_bg"
    android:text="热点排行"/>
 <Button   android:id="@+id/liangyiroom"
    android:layout_width="100dip" 
    android:layout_height="36dip"
    android:textColor="@drawable/color_wenzi_bg"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:text="我的靓衣间" />
```

```
        <Button android:id="@+id/preButton"
                android:layout_width="90dip" 
                android:layout_height="46dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dip"
                android:text="前页"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_default"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

               />
     <Button android:id="@+id/midchoth"
              android:layout_width="90dip" 
              android:layout_height="46dip"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
              android:background="@drawable/btn_default"
              android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              android:visibility="invisible"
              android:text="继续"
               />
      <Button android:id="@+id/backbu"
               android:layout_width="90dip" 
                android:layout_height="46dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
                 android:background="@drawable/btn_default"
                  android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                 android:text="后页"
               />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Header and Footer won't stay at their position. They'll be scrolling with the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Inflate the xml for ListView items. Create new xml say inflate.xml with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your activity class extend it with ListActivity, and do this

Create string array say "items" with multiple "First L Name"s as given in white screen like

```
String[] items = {"First L Name","First L Name","First L Name"};
```

Then,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setListAdapter(new NewListAdapter(this));
```

Extend NewListAdapter class with any Adapter like ArrayAdapter and do this

```
class NewListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {     
    Activity context;

    NewListAdapter(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.inflate,items);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
        TextView lblName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lblName.setText(items[position]);
        return (row);
    }       
}
```

Now run your code and see the magic...

Answer (score 0):

I did it my self here is the exact solution for the cause,

in layour i have added one listView

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LVfarmerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
```

in place of

```
       <ScrollView 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"

>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/LLforList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity ="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/IVimageIcon"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_farmer" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/TVFLNAME"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:text="Some Name"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

and created one more layout  which is

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/LLforList"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity ="center_vertical"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/IVimageIcon"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_farmer" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TVFLNAME"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="Some Name"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

now created one Activity(not listActivity)

in which i showed the layout, which have listview between top and bottom bar.

and created a customAdapter by using another layout, which which have one imageview and textview.

by listview.setAdapter , added this adapter into list view, and it worked for me.